# A div element won't inherit height in % from its floated parent and inherit it from its parent parent

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the folowing code

```
header {
Position : absolute;
Display: inline-block;
Width: 15%;
Height: 100%;
Left: 0;
Top: 0;
}

.headerchild {
Display: block;
Width: 100%;
Padding-bottom: 20%;
Float: left;
}

Headerchildchildeader {
Position : absolute;
Display: inline-block;
Width: 80%;
Height: 100%;
Left: 20%;
}
```

The problem is that my headerchildchild calculate the height from its parent parent header and not from its parent headerchild

Comment: Headerchildchildeader is a class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got what you want.

All you have to do is add **position** property in **headerchild**  child class, .i.e.,

```
 .headerchild {
   position: relative; //newly added property
   Display: block;
   Width: 100%;
   Padding-bottom: 20%;
   Float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Works perfectly, but can you explain to me what was the problem exactly